# How Can I return two variables from same method/function to one view in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm  a beginner with Laravel 5.4 but I'm stuck at some point. Please tell me how can I return two variables from one function / method to the same view. I've googled but all the contents are so old!!!

Here is my controller

```
public function index(Request $fetch){
      $category = Category::all();
      $fetch_cat = Category::find($fetch)->first();
      //$data = array('category' => $category, 'fetch_cat'=> $fetch_cat);
      return view('admin/create-menu', compact('data'));
}
```

I know I need to edit only this function and then in view I'll handle them.

Comment: Just tell me that how can I return these two variables to my view??

Comment: You want to **pass** two variables. **Returning** is something else in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$data = array('category' => $category, 'fetch_cat'=> $fetch_cat);
return view('admin/create-menu', $data);
```

or

```
return view('admin/create-menu', compact('category', 'fetch_cat'));
```

Comment: Got it!!!
Thats the way of laravel 5.4
Thanks

Comment: @DanishTahir up vote the question since you accepted it !!